# Why is my request always coming in with null values

Tags: c#, .net, axios

I am writing a very basic and hacky React and c#/.NET app to try to sharpen my skills. 
I am sending an axios request from the front but when it hits the route the data is always null.

call from the front end

```
    axios
      .post(URL, {
        "name": "me",
        "text": "Hello World",
        "date": "today",
        "userId": 1
      })
      .then(res => {return res})
```

My Message Class

```
    public class Message
    {
        [Key]
        public int MessageId { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My controller method

```
        public async Task<object> Post(Message message)
        {
            using (var context = new DbContext())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message);
                context.Messages.Add(message);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
```

When I debug and hit the breakpoint all of my values are null.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It is ASP.NET Core? Try to put `[FromBody]` attribute before your `Message message` argument to make the service bind this model from the POST body.

Comment: Yessss! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to put the `[FromBody]` attribute before my argument like this

```
public async Task<object> Post([FromBody] Message message)
{
    using (var context = new DbContext())
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message);
        context.Messages.Add(message);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Thanks to the comment on on my original post!